# excel document not open in browser and application pool is stooped

Tags: 2010, excel-services, iis

I created an excel service application and added in service connections proxy to the web application, but in app server where I enabled excel service application pool is stopped every time.
when I open excel document in the browser it shows below error.

> unable to process the request

when I check in event viewer I found below error

> The application pool  has been disabled. Windows Process Activation
>   Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application
>   pool because the application pool identity is invalid.